# How to Remove Angular js File from Source Code?

Tags: angularjs

When I run my project, it shows my all angular.JS files in Source Code. How can I remove the `js` files?

Comment: What exactly are you seeking to achieve? You question is a bit unclear. You can't remove the js files if you're using AngularJS.

Comment: When I Open Inspect elements in Chrome,Source Tab >> It's shows app.js file and other js files.Is it possible to HIDE the my own JS files from Souce tab?

Comment: I don't recall you can "hide" your `.js` files on web.

Comment: Paul is correct. You cannot hide them and there shouldn't be any reason to.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Gulp or web-pack for hide js files from source